# ZK Listbox auto sorted column after ListModel Update

Tags: java, zk, zul

I have a Listbox with a ListModel. I set the model on doAfterCompose then update the model from a timer component. The Listbox have a sort Comparator for each column. The problem is, when a column is sorted (ascending/descending) then the refresh event add a row of data, the data is appended as the last element of row and not sorted according to the column selected. How do I add a row then sort it automatically?

logs.zul

```
<?init class="AuthenticationInit"?>
<zk>
<zscript>
<![CDATA[
import java.util.Comparator;
import com.akarprima.dao.model.JobStatus;
import com.akarprima.util.JobStatusComparator;
Comparator nameAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.NAME);
Comparator nameDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.NAME);
Comparator dateAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.DATE);
Comparator dateDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.DATE);
Comparator sessionAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.SESSION);
Comparator sessionDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.SESSION);
Comparator sTimeAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.START_TIME);
Comparator sTimeDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.START_TIME);
Comparator eTimeAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.END_TIME);
Comparator eTimeDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.END_TIME);
Comparator durationTimeAsc = new JobStatusComparator(true, JobStatusComparator.DURATION);
Comparator durationTimeDsc = new JobStatusComparator(false, JobStatusComparator.DURATION);
   ]]>
</zscript>
<window border="none"
    apply="JobLogController">
    <label id="message" />
    <listbox id="jobLog" height="100%" sizedByContent="true"
        span="true">
        <listhead>
            <listheader label="No" />
            <listheader label="Date" sortAscending="${dateAsc}"
                sortDescending="${dateDsc}" />
            <listheader label="Session"
                sortAscending="${sessionAsc}" sortDescending="${sessionDsc}" />
            <listheader label="Job Name" sortAscending="${nameAsc}"
                sortDescending="${nameDsc}" sortDirection="ascending" />
            <listheader label="Start" sortAscending="${sTimeAsc}"
                sortDescending="${sTimeDsc}" />
            <listheader label="Finish" sortAscending="${eTimeAsc}"
                sortDescending="${eTimeDsc}" />
            <listheader label="Running Time"
                sortAscending="${durationTimeAsc}"
                sortDescending="${durationTimeDsc}" />
        </listhead>
        <template name="model">
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="${forEachStatus.index + 1}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.date}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.session}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.jobName}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.startTime}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.endTime}" />
                <listcell label="${each.value.duration}" />
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
    <timer id="timer" delay="5000" repeats="true" />
</window>
   </zk>
```

JobLogController.java

```
package com.akarprima.idx.controller.daily;

public class JobLogController extends SelectorComposer<Component>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4463081939576759090L;
    AppJobStatusDAO ajdao = new AppJobStatusDAO();

    @Wire
    private Listbox jobLog;

    private ListModelMap<String, JobStatus> jd = new ListModelMap<String, JobStatus>();

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception
    {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        jobLog.setModel(jd);
        refresh();
    }

    @Listen("onTimer = timer")
    public void refresh()
    {
        AppUtils.compareAddMap(jd, ajdao.getJobLogDailyMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: sort the listmodel again after a update.

Comment: I found that there is sort method for the [ListModelMap](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ListModelMap.html#sort(java.util.Comparator,%20boolean)). But it requires the comparator object. How to obtain the comparator from the current active sorted listbox?

Comment: check your headers, where the sort or sortdirection isn't natural => that's the one.